# Востановление состояние обьекта View

Tags: android, java

Имеется  активити с `toggle button` и служба которой выставляется режим работы с помощью этой `toggleButton`. Активити может закрываться, оставляя службу работать. Вопрос: как мне ззапуская активи, брать состояние режима из работающего сервиса  для иницилизации `toggleButton`? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вариант - через [pending intent](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/160-urok-95-service-obratnaja-svjaz-s-pomoschju-pendingintent.html). Суть - когда нужно узнать статус, формируем интент и отправляем службе. Она обработав, отправляет его назад, где собственно и анализируем.

Второй вариант - через [Broadcast Receiver](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/161-urok-96-service-obratnaja-svjaz-s-pomoschju-broadcastreceiver.html). Суть - приложение отправляет запрос. Сервис, когда решит, отправляет широковещательный интент. Плюс этого метода в том, что если сервис при этом меняет свой статус, то он может оповестить всех заинтересованных.

Третий вариант, более хитрый - через [ContentProvider](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/166-urok-101-sozdaem-svoj-contentprovider.html). Плюс этого метода - если нужно передать много данных. Например, адресная книга.

Comment: спасибо за ответы. воппрос не по теме: котируются ли те уроки, ссылки на которые вы дали? адекватные ли они?

Comment: как по мне - вполне нормальные уроки. До 50 урока явных ошибок не видел. Конечно, нужно не забывать, что андроид развивается и они немного устаревают, но не настолько, что бы это было принципиально.